# Edit the footer of lightning card

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-card

I have created a custom lightning page and it looks like the below screenshot.

[image]

But I want to place the delete button exactly before the cancel button

Can someone please suggest to achieve the same?

below is the code for the same

```
<aura:component controller="OverRideDeleteButton" implements="force:lightningQuickAction, force:hasRecordId" >
    <lightning:card >
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record</p>

        <div class="slds-docked-form-footer">
            <lightning:button variant="destructive" label="Delete" onclick="{!c.deleteRecord}"/>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: Nope, I am still trying to

Comment: @gs650x did you fix the footer of Lightning card footer with in `force:lightningQuickAction`?

Answer (score 5):

You can split your card into sections using aura:set's as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleCardCustom) (ex, ehader, body, footer), you might want to refactor your code to something similar to what is provided in the documentation:

```
 <lightning:card>
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:connected_apps" size="small"/>
        {! v.title }
    </aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="footer">
        <lightning:badge label="Tag1"/>
        <lightning:badge label="Tag2"/>
        <lightning:badge label="Tag3"/>
    </aura:set>
    Card Body (custom component)
</lightning:card>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but the above code creates another footer top of the cancel button but I want to add a button right before the cancel button

Comment: that is why i mentioend that you need to refactor your code to adopt the aforementioned structure, replace your footer with the ootb one from the lightning:card component

Comment: I have implemented "force:lightningQuickAction" and added the above component as a custom button now I nowhere define the cancel button but still, it is  there and if I use the above code provided by you it creates another footer instead of adding the button to the standard footer

Answer (score 0):

I've added some custom CSS on the footer div tag and then It worked in my case.

Note: add a class name where you want to apply CSS.

the codes are below like this.

.myFooter {
width: 93%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 80px;
background-color: white;
padding: 10px;
}